# The matplotlib chart changes when I change the index in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I have a dataset of S&P500 historical prices with the date, the price and other data that i don't need now to solve my problem.

```
        Date      Price
0     1981.01     6.19
1     1981.02     6.17
2     1981.03     6.24
3     1981.04     6.25
.       .           .
and so on till 2020
```

The date is a `float` with the year, a dot and the month.

I tried to plot all historical prices with `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

```
plt.plot(df["Price"].tail(100))
plt.title("S&P500 Composite Historical Data")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
```

[image]

This is the **result**. I used `df["Price"].tail(100)` so you can see better the difference between the first and the second graph(You are going to see in a sec).

But then I tried to set the index from the one before(0, 1, 2 etc..) to the `df["Date"]` column in the DataFrame in order to see the date in the x axis.

```
df = df.set_index("Date")
plt.plot(df["Price"].tail(100))
plt.title("S&P500 Composite Historical Data")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
```

[image]

This is the **result**, and it's quite disappointing.
I have the Date where it should be in the x axis but the problem is that the graph is different from the one before which is the right one.

If you need the dataset to try out the problem [here](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Eshiller/data.htm) you can find it.
It is called U.S. Stock Markets 1871-Present and CAPE Ratio.
Hope you've understood everything.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I found something that could cause the problem. If you look in depth at the date you can see that in month #10 each is written as a float(in the original dataset) like this: example Year:1884 `1884.1`. The problem occur when you use `pd.to_datetime()` to transform the `Date` float series to a `Datetime`. So the problem could be that the date in the month #10, when converted into a `Datetime`, become: (example from before) **1884-01-01** which is the first month in the year and it has an effect on the final plot.

**SOLUTION**

Finally, I solved my problem!
Yes, the error was the one I explain in the UPDATE paragraph, so I decided to add a `0` as a `String` where the lenght of the Date (as a string) is 6 in order to change, for example: 1884.1 ==> 1884.10

```
df["len"] = df["Date"].apply(len)
df["Date"] = df["Date"].where(df["len"] == 7, df["Date"] + "0")
```

Then i drop the len column i've just created.

```
df.drop(columns="len", inplace=True)
```

At the end I changed the "Date" to a `Datetime` with `pd.to_datetime`

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y.%m')
df = df.set_index("Date")
```

And then I plot

```
df["Price"].tail(100).plot()
plt.title("S&P500 Composite Historical Data")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you need any further explaination feel free to ask, I'll reply with pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to transform the date into an actual datetime index. This way `matplotlib` will automatically pick it up and plot it accordingly. For example, given your date format, you could do:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype(str), format='%Y.%m')
df = df.set_index("Date")
plt.plot(df["Price"].tail(100))
```

Currently, the first plot you showed is actually plotting the `Price` column against the `index`, which seems to be a regular range index from 0 - 1800 and something. You suggested your data starts in 1981, so although each observation is evenly spaced on the x axis (it's spaced at an interval of 1, which is the jump from one index value to the next). That's why the chart looks reasonable. Yet the x-axis values don't.

Now when you set the `Date` (as float) to be the index, note that you're not evenly covering the interval between, for example, 1981 and 1982. You have evenly spaced values from 1981.1 - 1981.12, but nothing from 1981.12 - 1982. That's why the second chart is also plotted as expected. Setting the index to a `DatetimeIndex` as described above should remove this issue, as Matplotlib will know how to evenly space the dates along the x-axis.

Comment: I don't get an error but the plot is similar to the wrong one. Read the "UPDATE" i wrote at the end of my question where I explain where the problem is imho

Comment: I found the solution. I wrote it!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your Date is of float type and taking it as an x-axis does exactly what is expected for taking an array of the kind `([2012.01, 2012.02, ..., 2012.12, 2013.01....])` as x-axis. You might convert the Date column to a DateTimeIndex first and then use the built-in pandas plot method:

```
df["Price"].tail(100).plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to treat `df['Date']` as `float`. It should be converted into pandas `datetime64[ns]`. This can be achieved using pandas [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('ie_data.csv')
df=df[['Date','Price']]
df.dropna(inplace=True)

#converting to pandas datetime format
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str).map(lambda x : x.split('.')[0] + x.split('.')[1])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m')

df.set_index(['Date'],inplace=True)

#plotting
df.plot() #full data plot
df.tail(100).plot() #plotting just the tail

plt.title("S&P500 Composite Historical Data")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]

[image]

Comment: it doesn't change anything. If you plot the tail you'll see the result is the same)=

Comment: There was a small typo in my code. Can you please check now. Please checkmark and upvote if it works for you.

Comment: I found the solution. Check it in my question if you need

Comment: Great !! However, you string solution could lead to some unforeseen bugs. pd.to_datetime is always better solution. I guess my solution didn't help?